# Updating dialog title with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am not able to update the title of a `p:dialog` using jQuery:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msgs.ViewPersons}" oncomplete="
    jQuery('#ui-dialog-title-viewPersonsDlgId').text('ciao');
    viewPersonsDlg.show()"> 
...
<p:dialog modal="true" id="viewPersonsDlgId" 
    widgetVar="viewPersonsDlg" dynamic="true">
```

The weird thing is that the second Javascript statement: `viewPersonsDlg.show()` is executed successfully and I don't see errors in Firebug. The dialog's title remains empty, or shows what I have put in the dialog's `header` attribute, if present.

I am not an expert in jQuery, and I have taken the jQuery syntax from the primefaces [forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8147). Probably I have misunderstood something.

Comment: First be sure that your selector returns the correct element. Invoke the jQuery command `jQuery('#ui-dialog-title-viewPersonsDlgId').text()`from the firebug console prompt and check what it returns. If it doesn't return anything, your selector is wrong. If you only have one dialog on your page, then you can select its title with a class selector: `jQuery('.ui-dialog-title').text();`

Comment: I have solved with Fallup's solution. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe me that there is no element with this `id` : `#ui-dialog-title-viewPersonsDlgId`. With hash sign you find element by `id`. `ui-dialog-title` is a `class` of `span` in `dialog` where `title` is defined and `viewPersonsDlgId` is its `id`. So correct code is :

```
oncomplete="jQuery('#viewPersonsDlgId .ui-dialog-title').text('ciao');viewPersonsDlg.show()"
```

**EDIT:** Deleted the previous part of answer which wasn't the cause of your problem. Also an important thing is that you have to specify correct `id` of your `dialog`, so if it is placed inside a `form` and you don't use `prependId="false"` in `form` properties then use `...#formID\\:viewPersonsDlgId...` (you have to escape ":" in jQuery with double slash)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have also tried that. Same behaviour: no errors, no update of the title.

Comment: With form outside dialog, everything works fine without jQuery. It's enough to use update=":myFormId". But I want to move the form inside dialog because I have read that sometimes the other way gives problems.

Comment: Try this code, I've tested it on simple snippet and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('#myDialogId').dialog( "option", "title", "ciao" );
```

Comment: This throws a Javascript error: $("#viewPersonsDlgId").dialog is not a function. Probably because PrimeFaces is automatically embedding a particular version of jQuery?

Comment: You're certain you have jquery-ui loaded up?